# Is it necessary to clearBatch and cancel if connected to Oracle?

Tags: java, oracle, connection

This is my code:

```
statement.clearBatch();
statement.cancel();
statement.close();
```

Is it necessary to `clearBatch` and `cancel`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`clearBatch()` clears the current batch so you can add a new one.

`cancel()` cancels the currently executing statement even in another thread.

`close()` closes the statement and releases any associated resources such as `ResultSets`.

They all do different things. You call them when you want those things done. I don't see that any of them implies any other.